# Change Values of multiple Columns in filtered DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I found here some quite similar solutions, but no one which shows exactly what I would like to do. This is my DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

sales = [('IPhone',150,200,50,100),('IPad',200,210,90,80),('IPod',200,210,90,100)]
labels = ['Product','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales,columns=labels)
```

Now I would like to add 1 to all Columns from Jan to April within the IPad record.

This works:

```
months =['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']

for i in months:
    df.loc[df['Product'] == "IPad",i]+=1
```

But does anyone know a way where I don't have to enter explicit every single month? Something like `Jan:Apr` would be perfect.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Jens

Comment: `df.loc[df.Product=='IPad',['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr']]+=1`

Comment: Thank you but this is not really an advantage. In my real case I have 36 columns and I want to avoid to enter them all. Isn‘t there a synthax with colstart:colend possible?